# How to create new string from old string in kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, query-string

i have created a new string inviteToken from old string inviteCode using replace but the value of inviteToken is not passing in startmeet function.

```
(deepLink?.getQueryParameter("inviteCode")?.substringBefore("?inviteToken=","") + deepLink?.getQueryParameter("inviteCode")?.replace("inviteCode","inviteToken") ).let {startMeet(it)}
```

on passing the string values in function startmeet. Its showing error: No value pass for parameter inviteToken

this is the code for startmeet:

```
private fun startMeet(inviteCode: String, inviteToken: String) {


    MyUtils.joinmeet(
        this,
        inviteCode,
        inviteToken
    ) 



}
```

Comment: `startMeet` takes two parameters, but you are passing one

Comment: Absolutely but i also created inviteToken(old string to new string) with some value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying the code would help you understand what is happening

PS: below answer is just based on assumptions on what you are trying to achieve

```
val str = (deepLink?.getQueryParameter("inviteCode")?.substringBefore("?inviteToken=","") + deepLink?.getQueryParameter("inviteCode")?.replace("inviteCode","inviteToken") )
```

The above line returns just one String value, and calling `let` on this variable will give you only one value.

Assuming you want both values in the above statement as separate string values

```
val inviteCode = deepLink?.getQueryParameter("inviteCode")?.substringBefore("?inviteToken=","")
val inviteToken = deepLink?.getQueryParameter("inviteCode")?.replace("inviteCode","inviteToken")
```

and assuming `let` was (incorrectly) used for null check

```
if(inviteCode !=null && inviteToken != null) {
  startMeet(inviteCode, inviteToken)
}
```